# Find $R$ such that $x>R$ implies $f(x) > 20$.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let f$(z) = z^3 + iz^2 + 8z + 3$.
Find some $R > 0$ so that for all $z$ with $|z|>R, |f(z)| > 20$.

My approach was to find the point where $f(z) = 20$ since as $z$ increases, $f$ increases. However, this point is a complex number (which I also don't know how to calculate).

I feel like I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Note that $|f(z)|=|z^3+iz^2+8z+3|>||z^3|-|iz^2+8z+3||$...

Answer (score 0):

For $|z|>24$,
$|f(z)/z^3|=|1+(iz^2+8z+3)/z^3|\ge 1-|(iz^2+8z+3)/z^3| \ge 1-(1/|z|+8/|z^2|+3/|z^3|) \ge 1-12/|z|\ge 1/2$.

Comment: Why are you saying greater than half? Don't I need 20?

Comment: After you times $|z^3|$ in the inequality, and use $|z|\ge 24$ , you will get the result.